# Making chat using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, chat

I want to make a chat system using javascript.I dont want any existing application.I need to know how chat actually works? Can i do it without any database?.Is it like checking a particular field in the database every x seconds.Or is it possible using http requests?.If so how can my request to a php page update a div in the other client's browser?

Code samples are appreciated..

Comment: sounds like you might want to take a look at node.js: http://nodejs.org/

Comment: You can do this quite easily with Node.js and DNode, if you'd like to use JavaScript (also on the server-side). Just call the server function on the client side the same way you call any JavaScript function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, yes it is possible to achieve this without databases.  Indeed flat files may be better, depending on your specific requirements.

As for your second question, no you should not be checking for updates every x seconds.  By checking every x seconds you're wasting valuable server resources, especially if your chat system is database driven.  Comet (or long-polling) is a technique that's especially suited for chat.  It works like this:

The client creates a connection with the sever, which stays open until the server signifies that there's an update.  The server then pushes the update to the client and disconnects.  The client then reconnects to the server and waits for another update.  This process continues for as long as the user is on the page.

This method is infinitely more efficient than calling the server every x seconds.  It is also means that content is pushed to the client immediately it becomes available.

Comment: So...how to check with javascript whether an update is coming or not?

Comment: You would use AJAX.  PHP does the "back-end" work, i.e. retrieving the new content, and Javascript to place the content on the page.

Comment: Do a Google search for "php comet chat" and you'll find a range of example implementations of this system.  But basically they all work on the principle that I've outlined.

Answer (score 4):

Node.js is a popular client-side server/client library that many utilize for Chat purposes.  There is even a demo on their site with source code http://chat.nodejs.org/

For a similar concept without a library, I'd recommend getting into javascript html5 Sockets http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/

Comment: I dont prefer to use any libraries...

Comment: then I recommend you familiarize yourself with the native html5 socket features of javascript : http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/

Comment: @JinuJD The library is only there as an underlying framework on which you would build a chat server, just as you might utilise the .NET framework to write a winforms application. There's nothing wrong with utilising libraries!

Comment: Understood...But what if i need to create a library?

Comment: why reinvent the wheel?  incorporate these open source libraries into your own library for your customized purposes.